# Can a ListItem's DisplayForm be accessed using query parameters on an arbitrary column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem, url, list-item, display-form

I'll preface this question by saying I am very much a novice when it comes to SharePoint, so apologies in advance if I use incorrect terminology. I am trying to find a way to access the "DispForm.aspx" (i.e. a list item view) for a particular ListItem based off the value of one of the Columns that has been specified as required to be "Unique".

I can do this for either the "ID" or the "Title" column with a URL like one of the following:

- https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?title=The%20ListItem%20Title
- https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?id=12

When I tried this with my own column (named "PID", which holds an external identifier via which we would like to link to the URL for the ListItem page):

- https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?pid=my_external_pid

But this only loads a blank version of the display form, not the actual ListItem data I expected.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? From what I've read, this could require creating a custom display form (which I think would have to happen through Power Apps, since we're using the "new" SharePoint, but I can't find any tutorials that explain exactly what I need, and since I have a limited understanding of SharePoint, I wasn't able to see anything obvious in either the form editor or the documentation that accomplished what I'm hoping to.

Thanks!

(EDIT to show behavior requested by answer below)

Here's accessing by ID (the normal behavior):

[image: DispForm accessed by ID]

Here's accessing by title, which also works:

[image: DispForm accessed by Title]

Here's trying to access by PID (a custom column specified as unique in my list settings), which doesn't work:

[image: DispForm accessed by PID]

Comment: It sounds like someone had a similar request here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/31cdeda9-8aac-471a-a1fe-a09f6bf530af/open-a-listitem-dispform-from-a-list-form-using-another-quotkeyquot-than-id?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy, but this looks to be in SP2010, and using Sharepoint Designer, which when I tried to use on our site, gave errors that I don't have permissions to change anything (even though I'm an "owner" on the site)

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can only get the display form while appending ID parameter to form URL. If I use any other columns, it will show a blank screen, such as Title.

[image]

Both in SharePoint server 2019 or SharePoint online(which use modern experience), I get the same test result, in my opinion, ID is an unique identifier to the item, so we could do this for it, if possible, please post a screenshot of your successful addition of the title parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've added some screenshots to show what I'm talking about. As an aside, our Sharepoint looks different... sometimes it has the "modern" view, but other times it has the "classic" view, like shown in my screenshots. I'm not sure what that means for what version we have, in case that makes a difference

Comment: Thank your for your screenshot, per my test, adding title parameter will only work in the classic experience for the list, ID Column(unique identifier) is the default and unique column to the list or library, other custom columns do not work, even if it is specified as unique later.

Comment: Do you know if there's any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to? Basically we want to be able to provide a value for the PID in the URL, and have it resolve to a page with the details of the item. My reading suggests this might be possible with a custom form, but I can't figure out where to start

Comment: Per my research currently we could only filter a SharePoint list or library using URL parameters, and no oob way to append custom column 
 to Dispform.aspx to show details of the item, please refer to https://natechamberlain.com/2020/05/09/how-to-filter-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-using-url-parameters/